# Which is the efficient method to display a text in View- MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I just want to display some text in my views based on culture.
I used label control to do that first

In view

```
 <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormDescription)%>
```

In model

```
      [DisplayName("Description")]
      [LocalizationDisplayName("CreateForm_FormDescription",typeof(App_GlobalResources.Label))]
       public string FormDescription { get; set; }
```

This works fine. Now i found another way to display a text in my view

In View

```
        <%: VoxMVC.App_GlobalResources.Label.CreateForm_FormDescription%>
```

Both methods shows my text in view perfectly.Which method is more efficient ??

Answer (score 1):

The second option is more efficient because it is a direct call to the constant value.

The first option relies on reflection.  However, your `ModelMetadataProvider` is already incurring the reflection cost when it gets all the model attributes, so the difference is marginal.

In general, however, assigning a value from a constant is much more efficient than getting a value from an attribute.